# Localizing clang output

Tags: localization, clang

Are the clang C compiler's diagnostic messages (warning, errors, etc.) hard-coded, or does it provide a way to specify which language (as opposed to English) to emit them in? Could I provide a custom dictionary for it to use at runtime, without building my own clang from source?

Answer (score 4):

Clang's diagnostics are currently hard-coded, but the system is designed to support localization.  You can read some information about how it works here:
  http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html#Diagnostics

We'd really like help localizing.  If this is an area that you're interested in helping out, please contact the [cfe-dev](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/mailman/listinfo/cfe-dev) mailing list!